# Browser back button redirects to first page of gridview, while it should redirect to last visited page of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a page complaintsearch which contains one gridview showing data depends on search criateria. Gridview have 20 pagesize and have so many pages. Every row of gridview have one linkbutton which will redirect to complaintActionform. It shows you complete details of that complaint.
Now when user click on browsers back button it redirects to complaintsearch page which is fine but it also gives you first page of gridview.
I want to redirect to last visited page of gridview.

Comment: You need to manage the PageIndex in querystring. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining GridView current page index after navigating away from Gridview page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991611/maintaining-gridview-current-page-index-after-navigating-away-from-gridview-page)