# asp.net c# obout Details Grid get current page Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, obout

am using obout Grid and am creating Details Grid i want to find out the current Page Index of Details Grid(child Grid)
 my Grid are below

```
<obout:DetailGrid runat="server" ID="GrdCategoryDetails" ForeignKeys="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,VENDOR_ID,ORG_ID"
    AllowSorting="false" DataSourceID="vendor_Details" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true"
    Width="98%" AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowPageSizeSelection="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    ShowCollapsedGroups="false" ShowFooter="true" AllowDataAccessOnServer="true">
    <ScrollingSettings ScrollHeight="250" />
    <Columns>
        <obout:Column DataField="ORG_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Org ID" ReadOnly="true"
            Width="0%">
        </obout:Column>
        <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Vendor ID" ReadOnly="true"
            Width="0%">
        </obout:Column>
        <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE" Visible="true" HeaderText="Broker Type"
            ReadOnly="true" Width="33%">
        </obout:Column>
        <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Amt"
            HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" ReadOnly="true" Width="33%">
        </obout:Column>
        <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Req Amt"
            HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" Width="33%">
        </obout:Column>
        <%--<obout:Column ID="Column1" AllowEdit="true" HeaderText="Edit" Width="100" runat="server">
        </obout:Column>--%>
    </Columns>
    <DetailGrids>
        <obout:DetailGrid runat="server" ID="GrdvendorDetailsGrid" ForeignKeys="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,VENDOR_ID,ORG_ID"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="false" DataSourceID="Vendor_Details1" CurrentPageIndex="0"
            OnUpdateCommand="GrdCategoryDetails_UpdateCommand" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true"
            Width="98%" AllowAddingRecords="false">
            <ClientSideEvents OnClientSelect="Select_Vendor" OnBeforeClientUpdate="validateUpdateAmount"
                OnClientUpdate="onCommand" ExposeSender="true" />
            <Columns>
                <obout:Column DataField="ORG_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Org ID" ReadOnly="true"
                    Width="0%">
                </obout:Column>
                <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Vendor ID" ReadOnly="true"
                    Width="0%">
                </obout:Column>
                <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_NAME" Visible="true" HeaderText="Vendor Name" ReadOnly="true"
                    Width="33%">
                </obout:Column>
                <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Amt"
                    HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" ReadOnly="true" Width="33%">
                </obout:Column>
                <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Req Amt"
                    HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" Width="33%">
                    <TemplateSettings EditTemplateId="tmpOtAmount" />
                </obout:Column>
                <obout:Column ID="Column1" AllowEdit="true" HeaderText="Edit" Width="100" runat="server">
                </obout:Column>
            </Columns>
            <Templates>
                <obout:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tmpOtAmount" ControlID="txtOUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT"
                    ControlPropertyName="value">
                    <Template>
                        <obout:OboutTextBox ID="txtOUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" runat="server" class="ob_gEC" Text="<%# Container.Value %>" />
                        <%--        <input type="text" id="txtOUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" class="ob_gEC" value="<%# Container.Value %>" />--%>
                    </Template>
                </obout:GridTemplate>
            </Templates>
        </obout:DetailGrid>
    </DetailGrids>
</obout:DetailGrid>
```

and here is my code for find the current page index of Details Grid

```
Session["CurrentPageIndex"] = GrdvendorDetailsGrid.CurrentPageIndex.ToString();
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue here, please can you explain bit more.

Comment: issue is that we have a nested Grid(child Grid) if am click on the Page number 2 of child Grid then we want put the Page number in session.

Comment: and what the error exactly you are getting....

Comment: is there any class with the name  'GrdvendorDetailsGrid' in your code?

Comment: GrdvendorDetailsGrid is the ID of Details Grid if you see my Grid Code then you will get it and there is no error but we are getting page index number is 0

Comment: yes I have checked that 1, I was making sure that you haven't created any class with the same name. Please try the code below if that helps to you, I have attached the source link for further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PageIndexChanging event of the grid to capture page index and store in session.

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    int PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting current page index you can try this

```
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request["myGVPageId"] != null])
        {
            myGridview.PageIndex =  Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request["myGVPageId"]);
        }
```

more help on [Maintaining GridView current page index after navigating away from Gridview page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991611/maintaining-gridview-current-page-index-after-navigating-away-from-gridview-page)

Comment: can you tell me that what is Grid_Change Please?

Comment: there will be an event for the Grid which calls on any changes on the grid like when we change the page

Comment: so where we can mention it i mean on which event?

Comment: can you confirm one thing for your code, have you tried by clicking again on any other page and check that it is giving 0 value always. As CurrentPageIndex is a zero-value based property, so may be possibilities that it is picking 0 value for the first time.

Comment: i think this grid is different from other web grids and they have only limited events for the grid. There are no events for any changes on the grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109553/discussion-between-a-t-and-sumer-singh).

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the paging on front-end, just do it this way

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# (Container.DataItemIndex + 1) + (gvReport.PageSize * gvReport.PageIndex) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Load the PageSize and PageIndex of your GridView